# React JS: Calling two functions in an onClick event does not run functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I'm using React and React Spring. React spring has a toggle function that essentially maximizes a window on click. It looks like this:

```
class Projects extends Component {

constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      instructions: true,
      data: ''
    }
  }

  handleClick ()  {
    console.log('hello world');
    this.setState({
      instructions: false
    });
    console.log(this.state.instructions);
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
       {this.state.instructions && (
          <div className="projects-instructions">
             Instructions here
          </div>
       )}
       <Grid
            className="projects"
            data={data}
            keys={d => d.name}
            heights={d => d.height}
            columns={2}>
            {(data, maximized, toggle) => (
                  <div onClick={()=>{
                         return data.clicks ? toggle() : false
                       }}>
                  </div>
            )}
       </Grid>
    );
  }
}
export default Projects;
```

What I want to do, is hide the instructions on click. I can make this happen by calling `handleClick` via, `this.handleClick.bind(this)` in my `onClick` tag via: `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}`. But that means I have to remove the toggle onClick function. So I found that I could call two functions like so:

```
onClick={()=>{
                  this.handleClick.bind(this);
                  return data.clicks ? toggle() : false;
                }}
```

The issue is that `this.handleClick.bind(this)` never runs. console.log doesn't even run.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Binding a function to `this` is normally done in the constructor. Are you sure you're wanting to do that in the `onClick` function? Maybe what you're wanting to do is `this.handleClick();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding `this` to a function does not call the function. It simply specifies what `this` refers to when used within that function. Bind to `this` in the constructor, and then, in your `onClick` event, simply call the function normally (i.e. `this.handleClick()`).

```
class Projects extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      instructions: true,
      data: ''
    }

    //this is where you bind `this` to methods
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick ()  {
    console.log('hello world');
    this.setState({
      instructions: false
    });
    console.log(this.state.instructions);
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
       {this.state.instructions && (
          <div className="projects-instructions">
             Instructions here
          </div>
       )}
       <Grid
            className="projects"
            data={data}
            keys={d => d.name}
            heights={d => d.height}
            columns={2}>
            {(data, maximized, toggle) => (
              <div onClick={()=>{
                this.handleClick();
                return data.clicks ? toggle() : false
              }}>
              </div>
            )}
       </Grid>
    );
  }
}
export default Projects;
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much! I'm still new to react and was super confused.